# How do make one onclick command out of 3 commands to fire with a delay and twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, onclick

How do make just one button onclick command out of 3 commands on the button to fire fire with a delay and to fire twice?

I need the command `copyDiv();` to fire twice and with a slight delay, wile the other commands within the same button to fire as default directly when I push the button.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function copyDiv(){
$('.content:not(.focus)').html(function()
{                   
    var value = $(this).val();
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr('name');
    $('.'+contentAttr+'').html(value
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
    .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')
    )
})
```

};

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="loadFileAsText();showFileSize();copyDiv();" value=" Load Text Default Files ">
```

**NOTE:** The source codes above work and do what they should do, the problem is that I need the command to fire twice and with a delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `script` tag, add this function:

```
function onClickCommand(){
  var count = 0;
  // delay in milliseconds
  var delay = 1000;

  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (count++ < 2) {
        copyDiv();
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
  }, delay);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="onClickCommand();">
```

Comment: Thank you, it works PERFECTLY. That is exactly what I needed. I am happy that for the first time on this page I get a correct answer this quick. You answered with a correct answer approximately 10 minutes after I posted it. THANK YOU...

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Although to be honest, i do not understand why i got -1 on it because the question was correct, and it is not a duplicate, and your answer was PERFECT what I needed. So really I do not understand why I got a -1 on it... Ou well that does not matter.

Comment: What matter is I got the correct answer, that works.